# Pip won't let me upgrade to the latest version of package

Tags: python, pip

How can I upgrade to 0.1.20 of ax-platform?

0.1.20 was released yesterday and appears on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/ax-platform/)

I have 0.1.19 and wish to upgrade to 0.1.20

If I run:

```
pip install --upgrade ax-platform
```

I just get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: ax-platform... (0.1.9)
```

If I uninstall and then install again with the above command or with `pip install --upgrade –-no-cache-dir ax-platform` “–no-cache-dir” I just get 0.1.19.

pip version 21.0.1

EDIT:
reason is one of the dependencies doesn't support python 3.6

Comment: try `pip install --user --upgrade ax-platform`

Comment: `ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install... in this virtualenv` I know what you're getting at - but this is in a virtualenv so it's not a case of different install locations.

Comment: Tbh I've seen this behaviour recently with offline installations. I tried to upgrade pip itself (from a wheel) because older pip couldn't install some other package. Yet all the time I got "already satisfied"... until I gave up, went do something else and tried again after some time. Then it magically worked. With the same command because I'm lazy and literally looked up the command with arrow keys...

Answer (score 5):

First, try specifying version on command line `pip install --upgrade ax-platform==0.1.20`. If it doesn't work it means that PIP thinks that this package is not available for your system (combination of Python version, OS version, CPU version, etc).

Second, you may try installing manually, go to [this page](https://pypi.org/project/ax-platform/0.1.20/#files). There download .whl file. And install it by `pip install --upgrade ax_platform-0.1.20-py3-none-any.whl`. If for some reason you don't see .whl file download link, [here it is](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/8e/41459c62930824383fe12d89968b9bd5e395210fc7fa3bd7af18f0bd40cd/ax_platform-0.1.20-py3-none-any.whl).

Also for any PIP package if you want to get .whl file manually, go to pypi project's page (e.g. [this](https://pypi.org/project/ax-platform/)), there on upper left of the page (navigation pane) go to "Release History", choose (click) version that you want, then on same navigation pane go to "Download files". There you'll see .whl files download link. You have to choose .whl file that suits your Python/OS/CPU version.

Also if PIP fails for any reason then try adding option `--verbose` to pip command line, it should help you to see real full reason or explanation of your failure. For example for `ax-platform` package it shows several debug screens of installing process and shows a message `Acceptable python versions are:>=3.7`, and you have Python 3.6, so it is definitely a reason of failure. Basically `--verbose` will help you debug real reason of failure of any pip command.

As it appeared to be that you have Python 3.6 and `ax-platform` needs Python >= 3.7. So only way to have the newest version of your package is to reinstall Python to 3.7 or newer or to use virtual environments with different versions of Pythons.

Comment: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ax-platform==0.1.20`
`ERROR: No matching distribution found for ax-platform==0.1.20`
hmm ok, this is ubuntu 16.04 on an x86_64 cpu

Comment: @ezekiel Try second step that I suggested by downloading .whl package manually. If for some reason you don't see a link, [here it is](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/8e/41459c62930824383fe12d89968b9bd5e395210fc7fa3bd7af18f0bd40cd/ax_platform-0.1.20-py3-none-any.whl).

Comment: thx! have tried, it fails because it cannot satisfy requirement botorch==0.4.0
I try and install botorch==0.4.0 with pip and this also fails, "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement" but this is also available on pypi https://pypi.org/project/botorch/

Comment: @ezekiel Do same stuff for botorch, go [to page](https://pypi.org/project/botorch/0.4.0/#files), there download .whl and install it. Direct link for botorch download [is here](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/99/41/21e2aac9ca831a2148ee7da44e00185c791d539c284cf0ebda34cd640e75/botorch-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl). It seems that PIP thinks your system is somewhat strange for it, that's why it can't install.

Comment: ok I just tried updating numpy too. it seems that I can't upgrade any packages at all

Comment: ah ok, when I try installing the botorch wheel it complains:
ERROR: Package 'botorch' requires a different Python: 3.6.9 not in '>=3.7'

so I think this is the root issue here. thanks for helping me get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @ezekiel Try adding `--verbose` key to pip when it can't upgrade. It should show real reason.

Comment: @ezekiel For me if PIP says that it can't find suitable version (short message), then I add `--verbose` flag to pip commandline, after that it shows several detailed log screens about whole search/install process. There in this log I can see for `ax-platform` package it says `Acceptable python versions are:>=3.7`. So in other words `--verbose` will always help you to figure out reason of any PIP failure, not only your case but for any pip command.